# Calculate difference of counter data in Hive

Tags: hive

I have counter data stored in Hive table. Counter increments in time and sometimes is reset to zero.

I want to calculate difference between consecutive rows, but in case of a counter reset the difference is negative. An example data and expected output is here:

```
data:       1, 3, 6,  7, 1, 4
difference: 2, 3, 1, -6, 3, NA
expected:   2, 3, 1,  1, 3, NA
```

Usually such an operation is done by calculating a lag and subtracting it from the data. In case of negative difference, we should put just the value from lag, here is an example of function, which does this in R/dplyr:

```
diff_counter <-function(x){  
  # count difference between measurements
  lag <- lag(x) 
  dx <- x - lag 
  reset_idx <- dx < 0 & !is.na(dx)
  dx[reset_idx] = lag[reset_idx]
  return(dx)
}
```

Can I do something similar in Hive?

Regards
Paweł

Comment: is there any column to specify the ordering?

Comment: yes, there is a time column which specifies order of data in time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `t` is your datetime column and the counter gets incremented in that order, you may use a `CASE` block with the `LEAD` function like this.

```
SELECT x
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (
                LEAD(x) OVER (
                    ORDER BY t
                    ) - x
                ) > 0
            THEN LEAD(x) OVER (
                    ORDER BY t
                    ) - x
        ELSE LEAD(x) OVER (
                ORDER BY t
                )
        END AS diff
FROM yourtable;


| X |   DIFF |
|---|--------|
| 1 |      2 |
| 3 |      3 |
| 6 |      1 |
| 7 |      1 |
| 1 |      3 |
| 4 | (null) |
```

Comment: Yes, this is, what I wanted, but one additional question: how to deal with using such construction with GROUP BY? t is not be in the GROUP BY clause and I get "Expression not in GROUP BY key " ?

Comment: @PawelStradowski : You may nest the query with an alias and use `group by` above it. Note that while using group by, you should have all columns included  in the `select` clause within `group by`. try to understand a bit more how to use group by in sql in general and  if you are not clear or you may ask another question. I hope this answer is helpful to you and solves your initial problem.